# Is it possible to use a function for multiple purposes? (multiple functions)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So to give you an idea of what I am doing: I made a function with an array in it, the array (so the function) is then assigned to the placeholder of an input field (also a seperate function). However I have a third function (also containing an input field), and this one should also have a random placeholder text. my question: Is it possible to use the function that holds the array to create another array and use that one for my other function? These are the functions which i'm talking about:

```
function placeholderRandomizer() {
    let arrRandomizer = ['Fill out the time you ran!', 'Hey! fill out the time you ran!', 'What was the time you ran this time?!'];
    let randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrRandomizer.length);
    let valueRandomizer = arrRandomizer[randomizer];

    return valueRandomizer;
}

function getInputTime() {
    let inputField = ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'time',
        'placeholder': placeholderRandomizer(),
        'class': 'form form-control'
    }));
    return inputField;
}
```

The funtion which I would like to use the `placeholderRandomizer` for aswell (but with a different array etc.) so basically one function should be randomizing 2 different input fields (so 2 different functions).

```
function getInputDistance() {
    let inputField = ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'distance',
        'placeholder':'tt',
        'class': 'form form-control'
    }));
    return inputField;
}
```

EDIT: What I mean is, I want a whole new array basically with new sentences and all that kind of crap for my other function, however it seems very unpractical to create a new function just for that, so to clarify the question: Is it possible to make multiple randomizers within one function and distribute those array randomizers to different functions.

Comment: Just pass the array to randomize as an argument?

Comment: `function placeholderRandomizer(arrRandomizer) {
    let randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrRandomizer.length);
    let valueRandomizer = arrRandomizer[randomizer];

    return valueRandomizer;
}`

Comment: So I can create 2 seperate arrays for 2 seperate functions, but with the parameters i'll be able to keep them apart?

Comment: Yes. `placeholder: placeholderRandomizer(timeMessagesArray) ` ... `placeholder: placeholderRandomizer(distanceMessagesArray) ` using `function placeholderRandomizer(arrRandomizer) { let randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrRandomizer.length); return arrRandomizer[randomizer]; }`

Comment: @mplungjan shouldn't I be returning the second array then aswell? (I know I havent made one yet). could you create this as an answer by the way? that'll be a bit easier to read. Thank you very much for the help by the way

Comment: Here is an alternative http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/eq5rbaw7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need two functions to do that. Then you invoke the `getInput` twice to get what you need.

```
function pickRandomItem(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function getInput(elementName, placeholderArr) {
    return ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': elementName,
        'placeholder': pickRandomItem(placeholderArr),
        'class': 'form form-control'
    }));
}

let inputTimeElement = getInput('time', ([
    'Fill out the time you ran!', 
    'Hey! fill out the time you ran!', 
    'What was the time you ran this time?!'
]); 

let inputDistanceElement = getInput('distance', ([
    'Fill out the distance you ran!', 
    'Hey! fill out the distance you ran!', 
    'What was the distance you ran this time?!'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using one array and template literals:

```js
function pickRandomItem(name) {
  let arr = [`Fill out the ${name} you ran!`,
    `Hey! fill out the ${name} you ran!`,
    `What was the ${name} you ran this time?!`
  ]
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function getInput(elementName) {
  return $('<input/>', {
    'type': 'text',
    'name': elementName,
    'placeholder': pickRandomItem(elementName),
    'class': 'form form-control'
  });
}
let inputTimeElement = getInput('time')
let inputDistanceElement = getInput('distance')
$("body").append(inputTimeElement)
  .append("<br/>")
  .append(inputDistanceElement);
```

```css
input {
  width: 250px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```